# Can a user's IP address in the middle of a browsing session?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

IP Addresses dynamically allotted by the Internet Service Provider sure do change as soon as the client computer is disconnected from and connected back again to the Internet, for example, when a Wifi router restarts, or the Internet goes down and comes back again, or when the client computer is restarted. Or if the client is moving and as a result their network or cell tower changes.

In these circumstances also, it is not necessary that the IP address will change.

However, my question is -- can an IP address allotted to a client computer change even when these circumstances do not exist? That is, can an IP address change if the user is stationary and in the middle of a browsing session with a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the IP address allotted to a browser can change while the user is in the middle of a browsing session. It just happened to me again just now.

The inquiry was not about whether a client IP could change in the middle of a TCP/IP client/server session. It was: whether or not the IP address allotted to a client machine could change while the user was browsing some website (though not in the middle of there being an in-flight HTTP request).

Since HTTP 1.1 is stateless (unless a TCP connection is persisted by explicitly sending the `Keep-Alive` HTTP header, or by using a web socket), the TCP connection is immediately terminated after each HTTP response is received, so it is not only plausible but is very common that IP's change in the middle of browsing a website.

It must be clarified here that the question refers to the word session to mean the equivalent of the duration for which the session storage is held in memory by the browser for a particular domain. So, for example, if the user went to `http://www.example.com` and then closed the tab, and re-opened the tab, two new sessions would have been created for the domain `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a TCP connections is (among others) defined by the IP addresses of client and server the IP address of a peer cannot change within an established TCP connection. but it can be that the client has multiple IP connections at the same time and that the next connection to the same server uses another source IP address.

This is especially true with IPv6 where it is not unusual that a client gets a new IP address assigned after some time. In this case the old one will still be active for a limited time so that established connections continue to work. But the new address will be used for new connections.